# Replace table with td and tr with div

Tags: css, html

I have the following  table structure

```
 <table style="width:100%">
                        <tr style="height:20px">
                            <td style="width:10;"></td>
                            <td style="width:20;"></td>
                            <td style="width:5%;"></td>
                            <td style="width:50%;"></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
```

I need to replace the above structure with div's. 
What is the best way to achieve it using CSS and DIV's only . I don't want to use Tables or td or tr tag's.

Comment: Just visit this solution http://jsfiddle.net/lvtrvd/v6say/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <style>
    .left{float:left;}
    </style>    
    <div style="width: 100%;">
    <div class="left" style="width: 50%;">1</div>
<div class="left" style="width: 50%;">2</div>
    <!--Next "Row"-->
    <div class="left" style="width: 50%;">1</div>
<div class="left" style="width: 50%;">1</div>
    </div>
```

Maybe something like this? Or did i missunderstand you? Use Float and it will "break" if you reach >100%.

[JsFddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fVqeb/)

Comment: thank you for the quick response . I also found another link which others might find useful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11488451/table-structure-to-css-divs?rq=1